# How to check the size of dependencies in an android app?

Tags: android, gradle

I'm working on an android app that already have many dependencies in it. I want to remove some starting by the bigger one's. How to check their size in the app?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I don't know whether it helps you or not but I researched and found this.

select the project from the dropdown.
go to your project.
now select the libraries.
right-click on the library you want to see the detail.
choose the file path and click on the libraries or you can choose your dependency library.
and go to the directory as shown in the figure below

[image]

[image]

[image][image]

> **Updated answer**

With the latest android studio, you can see the size of apk with apk analyzer very powerful tool to analyze the apk.

> 1. select **Build** from the menu and then select **Analyze APK..**
> 2. give the path to the desired apk and press **ok.**

now you can review the size of all the files you want to.

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like to check sizes in the context of my app. I mean like: App size 30MB, my code 10MB, Roboguice 5MB, ButterKnife 2MB and so on! :)

Comment: You can use [droidanalyser.tools](http://www.droidanalyser.tools/) for this purpose. PS I created the website

Answer (score 46):

In new Android Studio you can navigate `build/outputs/apk` folder double tap on apk file you are interested (there should be separate file for each flavor)
It will open a view like this:
[image]
there is `lib` folder where you can check a size of each library.
also you can se a size of resources and other stuf.

Comment: More detail on this APK Analyzer feature of Android Studio: https://medium.com/google-developers/making-the-most-of-the-apk-analyzer-c066cb871ea2#.966hvaob8

Comment: Double tap didn't work for me (after assigning Android Studio as default app to open apk) but Build->Analyze APK menu inside Android Studio did. Thanks for mentioning the tool!

Answer (score 11):

If anyone stumbles on this post, here is an even easier way to check.

All you have to do is compile your APK normally, take note of the size, then replace "implementation" for "compileOnly" in the library you want to check in your build.gradle.

This will generate an APK that crashes on runtime because it does not contain the library, but you can use it to compare and get the size said library adds to your APK.

Comment: Nice trick. The `Analyze APK` feature is unfortunately not useful to measure the size of a given dependency.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find my library in the list of the output of the APK Analyzer, so I went with the most straightforward solution:

1. Create a new project
2. Analyze the APK in release mode (Build -> Build Bundle -> Build APK)
3. After thats done, click on the button 'analyze'
4. Remember the size you see on the screen
5. Add the dependency
6. Repeat step 2 and 3 and than compare sizes