# How to analysis which dependencies caused huge app installed size (Not APK size)

Tags: android

My generated APK is around 6MB.

I am using ProGuard.

However, after installed into phone device, it takes up space around 60MB.

[image]

I would like to know, which dependencies cause huge installed space (60MB)

I look at [How to check the size of dependencies in an android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31633497/how-to-check-the-size-of-dependencies-in-an-android-app) and https://medium.com/google-developers/making-the-most-of-the-apk-analyzer-c066cb871ea2

I use "Build → Analyze APK".

[image]

But, it can let me know where does 6MB (size of APK) come from. But, it doesn't let me know, why it does take up to 60MB in user phone.

Google tooks most of the method counts.

[image]

But, I don't think Java code with ~40,000 methods and reference ~50,000 methods, can consume up to 60MB space.

I had checked my `assets` folder and `res` folders. Their size is 2MB and 3MB respectively. Hence, I have no idea what is the major contribution to 60MB app installed size.

Is there any good way, to inspect and reduce app installed size?

Comment: In my case it was the local database + log files + cache of images downloaded from the server after first run which increased my app size to 3x after installing, but clearly going 60 from 6 is something more than just db files. Will look forward to the answerof your question.

Comment: Backup the apk from actual device (using file explorer, e.g. ES file explorer), and then perform `Analyze APK` using that apk.

Comment: hi , @Cheok Yan Cheng  please check this question if possible, thank you   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42968587/android-email-client-receiver-email-id-empty-in-android-parse

Comment: I have same problem. I found that the images size are same between project, generated apk and installed app, so i think the most part of installed size is occupied by code that include libs. You can try removing some unnecessary libs.