# How to reduce the apk size (App size too big)

Tags: android, apk, proguard

Check my **gradle** config below.

```
    android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'xxx'
            keyPassword 'xxx'
            storeFile file('/home/xxx/AndroidStudioProjects/key/key.jks')
            storePassword 'xxx'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app.examinations.com"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner     "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            debuggable false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
    }
}
repositories {

    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    //Gson Dependency
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    //Design Layout
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    //chart
    compile 'com.diogobernardino:williamchart:2.5.0'
    //view
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    //fab
    compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'
    //expandable view
    compile 'com.github.aakira:expandable-layout:1.6.0@aar'
    //tables
    compile 'de.codecrafters.tableview:tableview:2.6.0'
    //Circular ImageView
    compile 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.0.2'
    //Download Images with Picasso
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    //Google Services
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.2'
    //Crop Image
    compile 'com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.1'
    //Pdf Viewer
    compile 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.7.0-beta'
    //Fab reveal layout
    compile 'konifar:fab-transformation:1.0.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I have used proguard and resource shrinking it is still 25mb (approx).

Here is the **proguard** config

```
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-keep class com.parse.*{ *; }
-dontwarn com.parse.**
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn com.squareup.picasso.**
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log { *; }
```

Check this **Apk analyser image**

[image: Imgur]

**Queries**

1) Is this lib folder contains all my libraries? And why it is too big?

2) Is there any way to use only the class I use from a library using proguard? Or should I optimise the size by using less libraries?

Comment: You are using many `dependencies `

Comment: What libraries are you using?

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Can I get any analysis which dependency takes how much space. So I can remove that or thing of other solutions

Comment: @apmartin1991 please check the end of the gradle config ,, its listed there

Comment: @Sp4Rx I meant expand the lib folder on apk analyser image so you can see which one exactly is causing the problem.

Comment: I would imagine it is going to be either: " compile 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.7.0-beta'" OR "compile 'com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.1'"

Comment: @Sp4Rx use fenflower application in order to use reverse engineering. You can use dex2jar too to extrude class ad check.

Comment: @Sp4Rx kindly review here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31633497/how-to-check-the-size-of-dependencies-in-an-android-app/31633842

Comment: "com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.7.0-beta" library is taking that huge space . Thanks @apmartin1991

Comment: @Sp4Rx I have put this as an answer, please mark it as correct if it solved your problem :) The other answers are great too!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is you are using many libraries, The worst of which being:

```
"com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.7.0-beta"
```

Libraries like this will be very hard to shrink and whilst there are many ways in other answers on how to reduce the APK size, this library is the main one you are looking for.

Comment: I can confirm that. This library uses too much space. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 4):

Here're some useful tips about Reduce Apk size:

- Use `ProGuard`
- Use `shrinkResources`
- Optimize your dependencies. For example, do not add all Google Play libraries to your project. Just add which ones you actually need.
- Use `SplitApk`
- Optimize your final Apk with Facebook [ReDEX](https://github.com/facebook/redex)
- Find your unused layouts and other resources with a tool (ex: Lint) and remove them.
- Use `Vector Drawables`
- Remove not needed localized configs with `resConfigs`
- Compile your debug libraries with `debugCompile`
- If you target Android 3.2 or above you can use `WebP` file format for images.
- If you're using custom fonts, check sizes.
- Compress your images.

You can find more information from Google's official [doc](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/reduce-apk-size.html).
Here's a useful [Medium Article](https://blog.mindorks.com/how-to-reduce-apk-size-in-android-2f3713d2d662) about reducing Apk Size.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this.

Answer (score 2):

1) The lib folder contains your libraries. It is very big because you use a lot of libraries.

2) You should be able to optimize libraries as well, but some are already optimized

---

Something I don't get is why you say the app is too big. Google Play allows for APK's up to 100 MB.

The best way you can reduce the size is to reduce image sizes. It doesn't look like you have any dependencies you can cut (the google play API's are split into several for an instance, if you imported the entire thing but only used Google PLay games, you could remove the dependency and only import Play Games.  this isn't relevant in your case, this is an example).

Comment: I'm concerned about the size as it affects user download.

Comment: All the tools can only shrink it so much. As long as you are under the point where you need expansion files, you are fine. If there is no problem related to it (except user aquisition) you don't need to worry about it

Comment: The main problem is with "com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.7.0-beta'" libarary . After removing the app size is reduced to 8mb. So I need to find a alternative for this.

Comment: Don't ask a question about alternatives to it. It is off-topic