# How to identify dependencies contributing to increased app size in build.gradle?

Tags: android, android-studio

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 34
    buildToolsVersion "34.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.tanzim.chat"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 34
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {


    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1'

    //libraries we need for now
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:17.0.0"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    //add this
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
    //add this library and this
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'

    //add these libraries
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.1'

    implementation 'com.github.ZEGOCLOUD:zego_uikit_prebuilt_call_android:+'
    implementation 'com.github.ZEGOCLOUD:zego_uikit_signaling_plugin_android:+'
    
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

}
```

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I'm working on an Android project and trying to decrease the app size. I've noticed that my APK size has increased significantly **(115 MB**), and I suspect that some of the dependencies in my build.gradle file may be contributing to this size increase.

I would like to ask for guidance on how to identify which dependencies are causing the app size to increase, and also I want to know how to decrease the app size.

Comment: Unclear if you've read: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/reduce-apk-size

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio's [APK Analyzer](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/apk-analyzer) tool can help you. Additionally, you can use [proguard](https://developer.android.com/build/shrink-code) or follow the instructions of [this page](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/reduce-apk-size) to minimize your app size.

To analyze the APK, go to **Build -> Build Bundle(s)/APK(s) -> Build APK(s)**

After the build is complete, click analyze at the pop-up that appears at the bottom left corner of Android Studio (you'll also find it in the notification panel) like the following screenshot:
[image: Screenshot of the pop-up]

After that, you'll see an analysis report like the following:
[image: APK analyzer]

To learn more about this tool, you can check [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/apk-analyzer).

I also recommend you view [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31633497/8192914).